# nest Command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, zsh, nestjs

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/) to create my first NestJS project.

Installing the Nest CLI with the command `npm i -g @nestjs/cli` was successful.

The output was:

```
+ @nestjs/cli@6.3.0
updated 1 package in 11.326s
```

However, when I try to scaffold a project with the Nest CLI:

```
nest new project-name
```

I get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: nest
```

Some details about my environment:

- OSX
- iTerm
- npm version 6.5.0

Answer (score 50):

Use `npx @nestjs/cli` instead of `nest`

e.g. `npx @nestjs/cli g controller pages`

Answer (score 15):

I was also getting the same console error when npm installing!

**Error was**

```
@nestjs/cli
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.14.1","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
```

How I was able to install:

**Solution**

```
sudo npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```

Comment: Never, ever, use SUDO with NPM as it may lead to security issues

Comment: care to elaborate on that? 
Anyway, installing a package globally requires elevated rights. Is there a way around this?

Comment: ok, here it is: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/main/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Answer (score 7):

Following command works in my windows 10

```
node -v 
v14.16.0
 
npm -v
6.14.11

npx @nestjs/cli new project-name
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, what I did was:

Installed the latest node with `npm install npm@latest -g`

and then added the following to my .bash_profile

`alias nest="/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/bin/nest"`

Tested with `nest --version` and it worked.

For some reason the path is not being called correctly, hope it helps.

Comment: Please note that this wont work since he's using zsh and not bash. He need to do the equivalent for his ~/.zshrc.

Answer (score 2):

After all the answers that I tried, I used my method

1. After installing `npm i -g @nestjs/cli` in my mac terminal.
2. open bash file in macos by typing `open ~/.bash_profile` in mac terminal. Like you can type it anywhere.
3. [image: Your bash will look like this, the highlighted area is for nest js cli]
   Your bash will look like this and use this line

   alias nest="~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js"
4. Restart your mac for changes to be reflected in your terminal.
5. There you go nestjs cli is now working globally 2nd screenshot.
   [image: Should look like this]

Answer (score 1):

Working through a NestJS/Mongo DB tutorial i stumbled into this very same problem. After trying all of the solutions that were listed above, even turning my default profile back to bash instead of using zsh, i found that simply adding the /usr/local/bin and ~/.npm-global/bin to my path variable resolved the issue. Hopefully this helps someone else who may stumble on this in the future as well.

export $PATH="/usr/local/bin"

```
export $PATH="~/.npm-global/bin"
```

Were the two commands i ran from iTerm2 in order to add them to my PATH environment variable. Once this was done a simple

```
env
```

showed the entries in my $PATH environment variable and the `nest -v` command worked without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error when I use GitBash.
I resoved it:
If you use windows:
Your use CMD: npm i -g @nestjs/cli

Then you can use gitbash:

- Check version nestjs: nest --version
- Create app nestjs: nest new name_project

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and solved ,following this

1. write the command `NPM root -g`
2. check where NPM is installed
3. add it to your path environment variable

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```bash
npm install @nestjs/cli --global
```

then

```bash
nest
```

will be available

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

This is needed so that the npm binaries are available on startup.

Comment: Still the same outcome. What worked is to add `alias nest="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js` to my  `~/.zshrc` file. But not sure it is the best solution as a future npm will need an additional alias.

Answer (score 0):

I have just succeeded with
`npx @nets/cli new project`
when asked what manager to choose from npm / yarn / pnpm
made choice for pnpm
`cd project`
`npm run start`
Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Must use **sudo** in comandline for linux, otherwise the command nest cannot be add to /usr/local/bin folder:
sudo npm install -g @nestjs/cli

Answer (score 0):

updating node version to 16 or more will help. I solved the issue by doing this.

*nvm use 16^*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I tried all the command to delete npm proxy and all

But nothing helped me.

In many cases some other services are blocking your network like your antivirus

you can try installing by restarting the system. this also help take effect of the commands you ran like the npm config to delete proxy

Simple thing try re-starting and installing your Nest js again.

it helped in my case probably will help you as well !

Answer (score 0):

I added this from my `.bash_profile` and it helped

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have an existing project at first install libraries

```
npm install
```

then build

```
nest build
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use sudo

```sh
sudo yarn global add @nestjs/cli
```