# Problem with installation of nestjs sh: 1: nest: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am facing the error by

```
npx @nestjs/cli rest_of_command_here
```

I have also tried to install using -g flag, -g --save-dev flag together but nothing seems to be clicking

```
sh: 1: nest: not found
```

I have tried the  answer [nest Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805275/nest-command-not-found) but it does not work as I face a new issue which says

```
bash: /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/bin/nest: No such file or directory
```

node version 16.13.2

npm version 8.1.2

Comment: Hey there! have you tried using ``npx @nestjs/cli rest_of_command_here``? I think this will determine if you have nest globally or locally installed.

Comment: Yup, that is the one giving the error in the first line. I will edit the question for more clarification

Comment: By all means, let me know what you have used already/tried will help me better understand and give help! cause npm install is different from the npx command. as ``npx`` executes a cli tool and ``npm`` is the package manager of course

Comment: I have tried npx and npm install only and whenever i install nest and cd into "/usr/local/lib/node_modules" I dont find nest package there. I have also done sudo npm install which is not working

Comment: can you do ``node -v`` for me? cause ``node/11.9.0`` feels wrong if you are using ``v16.13.2``

Comment: it shows v16.13.2 and I am on Ubuntu i guess i messed that up in a hurry ....

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `npm/yarn` does not install devDependencies if `NODE_ENV` variable set to production

I solved this problem by removing `NODE_ENV` from app configuration, and added `NODE_ENV=production` before running specific build script.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the alias was not working properly and had to set it like this

```
alias nest="~/.npm/_npx/ccf722f030a36e55/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js"
```